# VMware Fusion Player vms cannot use IPV6?

Tags: network, vmware, ipv6

Host is a Mac mini X86 running Sonoma 14.2.1, VMware Fusion Player Version 13.5.0 (which are current as of this writing.). Guest vms include Windows 11, macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, and a Linux, where I was best able to isolate and diagnose the problem.

Consider this transcript (with some extra blank lines for readability), which starts in `Terminal` on the host, and continues via `ssh` on a fresh (File/New/Create custom ...) vm running an installation CD:

```
scott@Mac-mini-x86 ~ $ scutil --dns |  tail -9
DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : attlocal.net
  nameserver[0] : 2600:1700:6b0:e60::1
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.1.254
  if_index : 11 (en1)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00020002 (Reachable,Directly Reachable Address)


scott@Mac-mini-x86 ~ $ ping -c 1 www.ibm.com
PING user-att-162-198-200-0.e7817.dscx.akamaiedge.net (23.0.23.183): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 23.0.23.183: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=14.879 ms

--- user-att-162-198-200-0.e7817.dscx.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.879/14.879/14.879/0.000 ms


scott@Mac-mini-x86 ~ $ ping6 -c 1 www.ibm.com
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) 2600:1700:6b0:e60:b9a0:4f76:4b85:6a1d --> 2600:1407:7400:d87::1e89
16 bytes from 2600:1407:7400:d87::1e89, icmp_seq=0 hlim=50 time=32.135 ms

--- user-att-162-198-200-0.e7817.dscx.akamaiedge.net ping6 statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 32.135/32.135/32.135/0.000 ms


scott@Mac-mini-x86 ~ $ ssh $vm

<---*snip a dozen lines of login banner omitted*--->

livecd ~ # ping -c 1 23.0.23.183
PING 23.0.23.183 (23.0.23.183) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 23.0.23.183: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=21.6 ms

--- 23.0.23.183 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 21.590/21.590/21.590/0.000 ms


livecd ~ # ping6 -c 1 2600:1407:7400:d87::1e89
PING 2600:1407:7400:d87::1e89(2600:1407:7400:d87::1e89) 56 data bytes

--- 2600:1407:7400:d87::1e89 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms


livecd ~ # ping -c 1 www.ibm.com
PING www.ibm.com(g2600-1407-7400-0d94-0000-0000-0000-1e89.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (2600:1407:7400:d94::1e89)) 56 data bytes

--- www.ibm.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms


livecd ~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by dhcpcd from enp2s1.dhcp, enp2s1.dhcp6, enp2s1.ra
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
domain attlocal.net
nameserver 192.168.1.254
nameserver 2600:1700:6b0:e60::1
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line
```

First thing to note is that although this example was run on an installation image in a fresh vm, essentially the same thing happens in a Windows VM or a macOS VM -- ipv6 doesn't work!

Back to the story: I ping `www.ibm.com`, both with `ping` (ipv4) and `ping6` (ipv6) while at the host -- works great, and quickly.  In the guest vm, the `ping` still works, and quickly, but the `ping6` just times out.  Why did I use explicit addresses on the guest?  The last experiment shows that on the guest, `www.ibm.com` will resolve to an ipv6 address (DNS lookup working, right?) but then can't be reached .

Note also that `scutil` (on the Mac) or `cat /etc/resolv.conf` (on the guest) both show that same addresses, ipv4 and ipv6, for `dsldevice.attlocal.net`, my router.

Perhaps there is some configuration magic in the `.vmx` file or something similar that could make ipv6 just work, or if not, make ipv6 fail in a way that things don't get confused, and just use ipv4 like the Before Times.

Comment: Have you asked here https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/bd-p/3005

Comment: This seemed like a more ... nerdy? ... community, but I have cross-posted the question there.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for several days. In my case, if I use an Ethernet wire instead of the iMac's Wi-Fi, and configure the Network System Setup on the iMac, and the virtual adapter setup on guests accordingly, I can use BOTH IPv4 and IPv6 on the guest. with no problems. I've been experimenting with /Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/networking, but the documentation on this config file is hard to come by, and is mostly from users' trial and error.

I've had no joy at all on VMware Communities :(

Comment: This is also an issue in Fusion 12 on Sonoma